# How to use Foreach inside of controls Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to creat something on Windows Phone,and Windows Forms i used that line of code to "navigate" into my controls and get everything was buttons.

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            if(item is Button)
            {
                item.TabStop = false;
            }
        }
```

But how can i do the same thing but on Windows Phone 8.1, Controls dont exist,and i know the "TabStop" now is button.IsEnabled!

```
item.IsEnabled = false;
```

Any ideia how can i do this ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A page can only have one child UIElement (UIElement is the equivalent of control), use this to get a reference to it:

```
UIElement mainControlOnPage = this.Content;
```

Usually, that one child will be a panel control of some kind, such as a grid. Use the following to loop through the children of a panel control:

```
foreach (UIElement element in this.mainPageGrid.Children)
{
    // do something with the element
}
```